# Graph theory : the adjacency matrix of an n-dimensional torus

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory

Is there, in principle, an easy way to determine the adjacency matrix of an n-dimensional torus that's *only* connected to neighbours which it shares a corner/edge/face/volume/etc with (n>1 obviously; the connections of a circular graph is obviously trivial). Can I use the 1-dimensional adjacency matrix to build the n-dimensional one? In this specific case the torus is formed by connecting the boundaries of an n-dimensional Cartesian like grid.

I believe I have a solution to the problem, but I can't find anything pertaining to the solution anywhere online or in an introductory book to graph theory that I have (perhaps mathematicians consider it trivial).

Comment: Which are the vertices of the graph?

Comment: I think this is a Kronecker product construction, from the lower dimensional adjacency matrices.

Comment: This is the way I've approached the problem (still not 100% sure it's entirely correct, but it seems to be checking by eye); do you have a link to any material per chance?

Comment: It may be a little trickier than I thought.  Have a look at this section of the Wikipedia article, [Cartesian product of graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product_of_graphs#Algebraic_graph_theory).  Compare that to the different notion of [Tensor product of graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_graphs) and you'll see why I say it's a little tricky.

Comment: Having problems posting my link unfortunately, but some of the stuff on the Cartesian product does seem to be similar to what I've got!

I stumbled across the same wikipedia pages yesterday while trying to make sense of this, but they seemed much less clear then than they do now (I suppose that's the beauty of thinking about something for long enough, though; it usually becomes clearer). Searching for 'Kronecker product construction' has yielded some interesting results!

Thanks :)

Comment: $$A_n = (\mathbb{I}+A_1)^{\otimes n-1} - \mathbb{I}^{\otimes n-1}$$

That's my solution! (Took me a while to figure out that the LaTeX functionality was based out of the text box! Bed time I think!).

Comment: I think that formula includes the "diagonal" connections, the case where $u$ is adjacent to $u'$ and $v$ adjacent to $v'$ results in an edge from $(u,v)$ to $(u',v')$, as well as the edges I described as being in the "Cartesian product" of graphs.  It's unclear from the opening paragraph in the body of the Question whether you mean to create such extra edges.

Comment: It's been a while since I asked this but I figured I'd respond to your message, hardmath. Hopefully it'll mean that future visitors have an easier time if they're searching for this question.

The idea was to indeed have directly adjacent and nearest neighbour diagonal connections (I was hoping this was clear from the 'corner' part of "shares a corner/edge/face/volume/etc" in my original post, however perhaps it was not so clear). The formula I arrived to was indeed what I was looking for in regards to this from memory. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 2):

As the $n$-dimensional torus $T^n$ is (topologically speaking) the [product of $n$ circles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus#n-dimensional_torus):

$$ T^n = S^1 \times S^1 \times \ldots S^1 $$

so too is the natural grid on $T^n$ resulting from equally spaced nodes on circles a [Cartesian product of graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product_of_graphs#Algebraic_graph_theory).

Suppose that $G$ and $H$ are simple undirected graphs.  Define $G \times H$ to be the graph whose nodes are pairs $(u,v)$ of nodes $u\in G$ and $v\in H$, with the edges determined by $(u,v)$ adjacent to $(u',v')$ if and only if:

- $u = u'$ and $v$ adjacent to $v'$ in $H$, or
- $v = v'$ and $u$ adjacent to $u'$ in $G$.

The adjacency matrix of a Cartesian product of two graphs can be expressed as a sum of two terms, Kronecker products corresponding to the two "cases" in the above definition.  Let $A$ be the adjacency matrix of $G$ and $B$ the adjacency matrix of $H$.  Then with a suitable ordering of vertices in $G\times H$, the adjacency matrix of $G\times H$ is:

$$ (A \otimes I_{|H|} ) + (I_{|G|} \otimes B) $$

where $|G|,|H|$ count the nodes in $G,H$ respectively.

To apply this to the "rectangular" grid on the $n$-torus $T^n$, we only need to iterate the Kronecker product expression above $n$ times, since the Cartesian product of graphs is (up to graph isomorphism) associative (and so too the adjacency matrix construction, with Kronecker product distributing over matrix sums).